# Android Start VPNClient (com.ipsec.vpnclient) Programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, vpn

I have an android application that requires VPN. My users will be using Galaxy Note 3's and will be using the built in "VPN Client" (com.ipsec.vpnclient). I need to find a way to launch this application from my application, in the instance of the VPN dropping. I've already figured out a way to determine if the VPN dropped, but I still need a way to launch the application.

**ANSWER:**
Thanks to help from @Muthu I was able to get it working with the following method.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ipsec.vpnclient", "com.ipsec.vpnclient.MainActivity"));
```

**EDIT:**
To add to the confusion, I am easily able to add a shortcut to the activity (`com.ipsec.vpnclient.MainActivity`) via another Launcher like ADW or Nova. I also tried using `com.ipsec.vpnclient.MainActivity` instead of `com.ipsec.vpnclient` in the method below, to no avail.

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ipsec.vpnclient");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above method works with other packages, but I can't seem to get this one to launch.

Here is the application when viewed in [Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en).
[image]

Any ideas on how to launch this application programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Start any installed application by using intent. in your case like this

```
Intent LaunchVPN = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ipsec.vpnclient");
startActivity( LaunchVPN );
```

Edit 
You can open pre installed apps that can be found inside settings page by

```
final Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
i.setComponent(new   ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: That gets me a NPE when I try it from my fragment (had to add `getActivity()`), or straight from an activity at `startActivity( LaunchVPN );`.

Comment: you can pass activity instance to fragment and you can use it with fragment. @JoshI

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally copied and pasted the wrong code from my application at first. I am already using the above method to launch. Still NPE regardless.

Comment: it may cause null if package not found

Comment: Which is exactly my problem, the package exists. I can use Nova or ADW launcher to create a shortcut directly to `com.ipsec.vpnclient` / `com.ipsec.vpnclient.MainActivity`, but I can't use the above method to launch them from my application.

Comment: use this `PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //  get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);` to get all information of installed app.

Comment: Ran that and dumped all the `packageName`s. `com.ipsec.vpnclient` is in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60092/discussion-between-muthu-and-josh-i).